# Determine if function is a jQuery promise

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have a page loader that can run a plain function, or a jquery AJAX request. I only want to move to the next step if the AJAX request was successful (ie `done`) and show an error if it wasn't (ie `fail`).

```
function runStep(stepText, functionToCall){
   this.setStepText(stepText);
   // call function
   let result = functionToCall();
   // if the function is jquery, wait for the result
   if(result && typeof result.then === 'function'){
       let self = this;
       result.done(function(){ 
           self.goToNextStep();
       }).fail(function(){ 
           self.showFailureMsg();
       });
   }
   // if its a plain old function go to the next step   
   else {
      this.goToNextStep();
   }      
}
```

What I don't get is; at the point I call `done` or `faile`, I've already run the jQuery AJAX request. So is it not too late to attach these handlers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nice thing about Promises is that it doesn't matter when you attach.  Once they finalize, the state is constant.

In this way you can pass around a resolved or rejected Promise throughout the lifetime of your app and late listeners will still be called.

```js
const pg = Promise.resolve("foo");
const pb = Promise.reject("bar");

pg.then(v => console.log(v));
pb.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Since jqXHR Objects (which is what [`$.ajax()` returns](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR)) implement the same interface as Promise, you can also attach whenever you want as well.

```js
const d = $.Deferred();
const dpr = d.promise();
d.resolve("foo");

dpr.then(v => console.log(v));

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Even 3 seconds later it's still foo");
  dpr.then(v => console.log(v));
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Consider this concrete example that uses a real XHR:

```js
const post = $.ajax("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");

post.then(p => {
  // We are in the callback of the request 
  // so we know that it is complete
  console.log(p.title);

  // Let's add another callback when we *think*
  // it should be too late
  post.then(latep => {

    // Still possible
    console.log(p.title)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```